# What does the :ls command do in VIM Adventures?

Tags: vim-adventures

I don't understand the output of `:ls` (note no exclamation point) in [VIM Adventures](https://vim-adventures.com/). Here's what it says for me:

```
1   %   ground
```

Anyone know what that means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Vim Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Buffers):

> To list all buffers use the :ls command. Each buffer is assigned a number that is displayed in the first column.
>
> The second column describes the state of the buffer. The different states are explained at [:help :ls](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/help?tag=%3Als). The third column is the file name associated with the buffer.

So the first column is just a number for what buffer it is.  Looking at the :help :ls page, `%` means the buffer is the current window. Lastly, `ground` simply means the name of the file that is associated with the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with level 11, you have to be able to switch between the buffers.  One is named "ground", which is the only one you can see (with the `:ls` command) before level 11.